# MSAccess database update not updating using c#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2010

I am making a database system. I've implemented the INSERT function properly but when I tried implementing the UPDATE function, I couldn't make any changes to the database. I don;t know where I went wrong.
Note: username is declared as string

Here is the function handling the UPDATE:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string q = "UPDATE [registrationinfo] SET [Password]='?', [EmailAdd]='?', [HomeAdd]='?' WHERE [Username]='?'";

        OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(MyConnectionString);
        connect.Open();
        try
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(q,connect);

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txt_password.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAdd", txt_eadd.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeAdd", txt_homeadd.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", username);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            txt_password.Clear();
            txt_eadd.Clear();
            txt_homeadd.Clear();
            txt_conPass.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            connect.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }

        connect.Close();            
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a parameterized query you do *not* need to put single quotes (`'`) around text parameters in your CommandText, so you should be using something like this:

```
string q = "UPDATE [registrationinfo] SET [Password]=?, [EmailAdd]=?, [HomeAdd]=? WHERE [Username]=?";
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked it... :) appreciate it much... now I can graduate... ~~

Comment: @marijanluvlee Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer, if it answers your question.